# Partitioning a convex object without harming existing convex subsets

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

$C$ is a convex planar figure and $C_1,\dots,C_n$ are pairwise-disjoint convex subsets of $C$, like this:

[image]

A **convex-preserving partition** of $C$ is a partition $C=E_1\cup\dots\cup E_N$, , such that $N\geq n$, the $E_i$ are pairwise-disjoint convex figures, and for every $i=1,\dots,n$: $C_i\subseteq E_i$, i.e, each existing figure is contained in a unique new figure, like this:

[image]

For every $C,C_1,\dots,C_n$, let $F(C,C_1,\dots,C_n)$ be the smallest cardinality $N$ of a convex-preserving partition.

For every $n$, let $G(n)$ be the largest value of $F(C,C_1,\dots,C_n)$, for all combinations of $C,C_1,\dots,C_n$.

**What is $G(n)$?**

- Obviously $G(1)=1$.
- By the half-plane separation theorem, $G(2)=2$.
- By the above figure, $G(3)\geq 4$; there is apparently no convex-preserving partition with $N=3$.

What more can be said about $G(n)$?

*Remark: I asked a [similar question in cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/33744). There, $C$ and all its subsets were axis-parallel rectangles. In that case, I found an algorithm that proves $G(n)\leq 3n+1$.*

Comment: I feel like the notion of [Davenport-Schinzel sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport%E2%80%93Schinzel_sequence) may be relevant to this problem - in particular, from the centroid of your body then the bodies that can be 'seen' in a circular arc form a D-S sequence of order 2 (no $xyxy$ sequences exist).  You might be able to use this for some sort of onion-skin algorithm that achieves linear time complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the number of holes is not greater than two times the number of sets $C_i$.

Note that the sets $C_i$ can be extended to $E_i$ in a such way that all holes will be convex (see page 8 in paper of Rom Pinchasi, On the perimeter of $k$ pairwise disjoint convex bodies contained in a convex set in the plane. http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~room/ps_files/perim_k_convex.pdf). Lets think about $C_i$ as about already extended sets.

Each side of a hole is formed by one of the $C_i$-s. Lets call two sets $C_i$ and $C_j$ *neighbors*, if they form two adjacent sides of some hole. Note that:

- To each hole correspond at least 3 neighbor-pairs - since each hole has at least 3 sides.
- To each neighbor-pair $C_i,C_j$ correspond at most two holes - since all such holes must have a side co-linear with the segment in which the boundaries of $C_i$ and $C_j$ intersect.

Therefore, the number of holes is at most 2/3 the number of neighbor-pairs.

The "neighbor" relation defines a planar graph with $V=n$ vertexes. [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) implies that in a planar graph (with at least 3 vertexes) the number of edges is bounded by: $E\leq 3V-6$. Hence, the number of holes is at most $2n-4$. Hence, $G(n)\leq 3n-4$.

The lower bound gives the tiling shown on the figure:

[image]

In the infinite tiling, each hexagon touches 6 holes and each holes touches 3 hexagons, so the number of holes is exactly $2n$. In the finite tiling, the number of holes is smaller since the holes near the boundary can be attached to their neighboring hexagons. So the number of holes is $2n-o(n)$ and $G(n)\geq 3n-o(n)$.

Comment: By "to each pair of neighborhood sets correspond at most two holes" you mean "to each unordered pair $\{i,j\}$, there are at most two different holes such that $C_i,C_j$ are neighbors of these holes"?

Comment: What exactly is the lower bound? $G(n)=...$?

Comment: About $2n+$const

Comment: Or I am too optimistic and bounds are $2n+O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: On my deleted answer: I deleted my answer because I found an error in my construction.

Comment: I did not understand the sentence: "The neighborhood sets form a planar graph, so the number of "neighboring" is (at most) approximately 3n". I tried to prove it  using Euler's formula, where there are $m$ vertexes (the $C_i$-s), but did not know how to calculate the number of faces.

Comment: Each face is at least 3-gon. So, 2E>3F. Applying the Euler formula we get V-F/2>2 therefore V>F/2 (+2)